# Exclude li in ul from being treated as a tab by jquery-ui tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-tabs

[image: Picture of what I want, and that SORT OF works right now, but not fully]

I have a tab list (ul using jquery-ui) that I have stretch width-wise across the entirety of the page.  In the top-right corner of the themed/tab area (not outside of the tabbed area, but INSIDE of it) I want another set of navigation that I want themed differently.

So I made another ul and nested it in the last li in my parent ul.  And then apply css to override the jquery-ui themes that get applied to the rest of the tabs.  This works, except for two things:
1.) I want the gap between this nested list, and the last real tab in my tabstrip to shrink as the browser changes size, and if it needs to wrap to the bottom (like the rest of the tabs do).
2.) The first li in my nested ul is being treated like it's still a tab, and so when I click on it, rather than it be a link to another page ("/Store/Admin/") that I specify in the href property, jquery-ui shoves in "#ui-tabs-1" and tries to post back to an anchor on the current page that doesn't exist.  I don't know where "#ui-tabs-1" came from because that's not even my naming convention for my parent ul/tab-list???  I don't any of the nested list to be treated as still part of the tab list.

If I need to un-nest the other ul and put it somewhere else on the page, that is fine with me... BUT, I still want it to be sitting in the top-right section of my tablist and I want it to wrap with the tabs, so that's why I shoved it in the last/right-most li of my parent ul.

Is there a way to tell jquery "don't treat this li as a tab"?

The code on my page looks something like:

```
<article>
    <div id="tabs">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#Parts" onclick="getTab('Parts');">Parts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Categories" onclick="getTab('Categories');">Categories</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Links" onclick="getTab('Links');">Links</a></li>
                <li class="untabbed">
                    <ul>
                        <li>[ <a href="/Store/Admin">Admin</a> |</li>
                        <li><a href="/Store/Order">Order</a> |</li>
                        <li><a href="/Account/LogOff">Log off</a> ]</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="Parts"></div>
        <div id="Categories"></div>
        <div id="Links"></div>
    </div>

</article>
    ...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 'Categories');
    getTab('Categories');
    function getTab(id) {
        var url = '/Store/Home/GetTab/' + id;
        var targetDiv = '#' + id;
        $.get(url, null, function (result) {
            $(targetDiv).html(result);
        });
    }
    $.address.change(function (event) {
        $('#tabs').tabs('select', window.location.hash)
    });
    $('#tabs').bind('tabsselect', function (event, ui) {
        window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: +1 for a well set out question. It always helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the disabled option to select tabs to exclude.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

> An array containing the position of the tabs (zero-based index) that
>   should be disabled on initialization.

**For example:**

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ disabled: [1, 2] });
```

**UPDATE**

After our comments I've done a JSFiddle of a solution that takes the sub list out of the tabbed list.

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/G6WhC/17/

Comment: Though I say this, you could just split the HTML up. I don't see much need for it to be a sub list.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be a sub-list... my problem is, I want it wrapped in the CSS that jquery-ui is adding to the first list, but just shoved up into the top right corner of it.  So my little way of doing that was by making it a sub-list.

I'll expirement with the disabled option (THANK YOU FOR THAT!).  I'll have to tweak it for dynamics/scalability because I won't be able use static values since my tabs are based off of what type of user logs in.

Comment: Have a look at disabled. Otherwise I'd set the nice wrapping CSS to a wrapper element rather than the UI bits. Probably easier in the long run.

Comment: Tried the disabled property and jquery-ui is still adding the '#ui-tabs-1' and removing my original link that I had in place on the 'href' property of 'a' contained inside my frist 'li' in the sub-list.  It's strange, cause it ONLY does it to the FIRST 'li' in the sub-list and not any of the others after that.  And it's some default list anchor scheme because the rest of my anchors in my main list don't look anything like '#ui-tabs-1'.  All of the anchors in the parent list just have their anchor set as their name.

Comment: So navigation in the main list looks like: /Store/Home#Products, /Store/Home#Categories, /Store/Home#Links, etc..  NONE of them are in the format of #ui-tabs-1.  That makes me believe that jquery-ui is auto-adding that... and I just can't figure out how to stop it, nor WHY it's ONLY doing it to the first sub-list 'li' ???  It's weird to me since I'm new to jquery-ui.

Comment: Could you set an example up on JSFiddle for me to look at?

Comment: Notice how "[ Admin | Order | Log off ]" is INSIDE the tabbed themed section, I want this BUT I want it up in the top right. BUT MORE IMPORTANTLY: If you notice, the tabs all work great.  And "Order" and "Log Off" on the sublist work great and try to take you to the other pages they're linked to (/Store/Order and /Store/LogOff) BUT Admin gets the default tab treatment and it's link that I've specified gets ripped out and changed from /Store/Admin to /CurrentPage/#ui-tabs-1. I don't know why it keeps trying to auto-change just this first item in the sub-list and not the rest or how to stop it.

Comment: From the fiddle? Sure, fiddle with it all you please.

Comment: I created that as anonymous because I hadn't created a jsfiddle account yet.  So you may have to fork it?  I dunno.

Comment: If it helps, here's a duplicate one I made under my profile/account:
http://jsfiddle.net/soteriologist/6TLt5/

Comment: BEAUTIFUL!  Thank you my friend!  I'm going to have to find another way of putting it top right (or maybe I'll just let it sit butted up against the tabs if I can't) because I've done the whole position relative thing and it isn't very flexible (if someone has a smaller browser and/or is mobile it overlays on the tabs and I want it to stack with them.  But I'll keep playing around with that.  At least now my tabs are working proper and for that I thank you a MILLION times!

Comment: Oh, and ya... I know !Important isn't good to use all too often, I was just shoving it in there to make sure during testing that my css was getting applied and that I wasn't see any of the default stuff screw with mine.  But now that I'm done fiddling around I don't need them any longer.  Thanks again man!

Comment: Awesome. You could use percentages in top etc for mobiles.